# How to configure fasterxml's objectMapper to handle empty string "" correctly

Tags: java, json, serialization, fasterxml

I'm using fasterxml's ObjectMapper to serialize a java object and I'm having a problem with one of the fields.

Survey.java

```
public class Survey {

  private String id;
  private String answers;

  //getter and setter
}
```

This is the serialization code:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();                   
ObjectWriter ow = om.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();           
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(taskScheme.getSurvey());
```

the problem is that "answers" contains multiple values, and the serialization process escapes all the double quotes, like so:

```
"answers" : {"question3":["Item4"]} -> "answers" : "{\"question3\":[\"Item4\"]}"
```

In order to avoid this situation, I added the annotation @JsonRawValue to the "answers" field. It solved my problem but created a new one, because now whenever "answers" contains an empty string, the resulting serialization becomes:

```
"answers" : "" -> "answers" :
```

which is not even a valid JSON output...

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So it looks like your `answers` field doesn't contain "mutliple values", it contains an actual JSON string. Jackson is already handling it correctly: JSON strings should be escaped. Now, if you want to include your "answers" in the JSON object instead of as a JSON-string inside another JSON object, you should change your `Survey` class to contain `Answer` objects, instead of a String.

Comment: Or, if you insist on using `JsonRawValue`, just make sure that you subsitute "{}" for the empty string. But then you're just working around Jackson, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: you are right, I should create an Answer object. But the problem is that the content of "answers" can change, I cannot define its fields in advance.

Comment: Assuming there are a finite number of possible answer types, Jackson has ways to handle that. You should look into `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it and hopefully post my solution.